# Swiper.js CMS column grid doesn't stop when scrolling towards the right. (webflow)

Tags: javascript, grid, content-management-system, swiper.js, webflow

I'm made a 3 x 3 grid with swiper.js (in webflow).
But I keep bumping on 1 problem.
Whenever I scroll towards the right, swiper keeps going even though there are no more items to be viewed. Is the reason for this problem that I'm using the column on my swiper wrapper?
https://9300.webflow.io/

```
const portfolioSlider = new Swiper(".swiper.is-portfolio", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  slidesPerColumn: 3,
  slidesPerGroup: 3,
});
```

Is the site I'm working on.
https://9300.webflow.io/

Tried:
Looping
Changing grid sizes etc..